# How to find namespace of tables in Delta Live Tables to query?

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I created a pipeline using Delta Live Tables.

How to know the namespace of the tables?

The name of this DLT pipeline is "dlt_test", then I tried

```
select * from dlt_test.live_gold
select * from dlt_test_dlt_db.live_gold
```

However, both failed and returned:

```
[TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view `dlt_test_dlt_db`.`live_gold` cannot be found.
```

So how to query the tables in DLT?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check DLT pipeline settings - click on "Settings" button, and there you will see two options:

- Target schema if you're registering in the Hive Metastore

[image]

- Target catalog & schema if you storing data in Unity Catalog

[image]

Also it could be possible that tables aren't registered in either Hive Metastore or in the Unity Catalog.   In this case, you will need to see where data is stored (the "Storage location" option), then all tables will be in the `tables` directory under that location.